RI-CLPM - do we need to restrict residual variances of factors to 0?
I am currently exploring Random Intercept Cross-Lagged Panel Models (Hamaker, 2015) using the lavaan code provided in this website https://jeroendmulder.github.io/RI-CLPM/lavaan.html#extension-3-multiple-indicators. There is a section of code given that requires setting the residual variances of all factors to 0. This was done as:
# Set residual variances of all FX and FY variables to 0
  FX1 ~~ 0*FX1
  FX2 ~~ 0*FX2
  FX3 ~~ 0*FX3
  FX4 ~~ 0*FX4
  FX5 ~~ 0*FX5
  FY1 ~~ 0*FY1
  FY2 ~~ 0*FY2
  FY3 ~~ 0*FY3
  FY4 ~~ 0*FY4
  FY5 ~~ 0*FY5

The whole code for the model is:
RICLPM5.ext3 <- '
  
  #####################
  # MEASUREMENT MODEL #
  #####################
  
  # Factor models for X at 5 waves (constrained)
  FX1 =~ a*x11 + b*x12 + c*x13
  FX2 =~ a*x21 + b*x22 + c*x23
  FX3 =~ a*x31 + b*x32 + c*x33
  FX4 =~ a*x41 + b*x42 + c*x43
  FX5 =~ a*x51 + b*x52 + c*x53
  
  # Factor models for Y at 5 waves (constrained)
  FY1 =~ d*y11 + e*y12 + f*y13
  FY2 =~ d*y21 + e*y22 + f*y23
  FY3 =~ d*y31 + e*y32 + f*y33
  FY4 =~ d*y41 + e*y42 + f*y43
  FY5 =~ d*y51 + e*y52 + f*y53
  
  # Constrained intercepts over time (this is necessary for strong factorial 
  # invariance; without these contraints we have week factorial invariance)
  x11 + x21 + x31 + x41 + x51 ~ g*1
  x12 + x22 + x32 + x42 + x52 ~ h*1
  x13 + x23 + x33 + x43 + x53 ~ i*1
  y11 + y21 + y31 + y41 + y51 ~ j*1
  y12 + y22 + y32 + y42 + y52 ~ k*1
  y13 + y23 + y33 + y43 + y53 ~ l*1
  
  # Free latent means from t = 2 onward (only do this in combination with 
  # constraints on intercepts; without these, this would not be identified)
  FX2 + FX3 + FX4 + FX5 + FY2 + FY3 + FY4 + FY5 ~ 1
  
  ################
  # BETWEEN PART #
  ################
  
  # Create between factors (random intercepts)
  RIX =~ 1*FX1 + 1*FX2 + 1*FX3 + 1*FX4 + 1*FX5
  RIY =~ 1*FY1 + 1*FY2 + 1*FY3 + 1*FY4 + 1*FY5
  
  **# Set residual variances of all FX and FY variables to 0
  FX1 ~~ 0*FX1
  FX2 ~~ 0*FX2
  FX3 ~~ 0*FX3
  FX4 ~~ 0*FX4
  FX5 ~~ 0*FX5
  FY1 ~~ 0*FY1
  FY2 ~~ 0*FY2
  FY3 ~~ 0*FY3
  FY4 ~~ 0*FY4
  FY5 ~~ 0*FY5**
  
  ###############
  # WITHIN PART #
  ###############
 
  # Create within-components
  WFX1 =~ 1*FX1
  WFX2 =~ 1*FX2
  WFX3 =~ 1*FX3
  WFX4 =~ 1*FX4
  WFX5 =~ 1*FX5
  
  WFY1 =~ 1*FY1
  WFY2 =~ 1*FY2
  WFY3 =~ 1*FY3
  WFY4 =~ 1*FY4
  WFY5 =~ 1*FY5
  
  # Specify lagged effects between within-person centered latent variables
  WFX2 + WFY2 ~ WFX1 + WFY1
  WFX3 + WFY3 ~ WFX2 + WFY2
  WFX4 + WFY4 ~ WFX3 + WFY3
  WFX5 + WFY5 ~ WFX4 + WFY4
  
  # Estimate correlations within same wave
  WFX2 ~~ WFY2
  WFX3 ~~ WFY3 
  WFX4 ~~ WFY4
  WFX5 ~~ WFY5
  
  ##########################
  # ADDITIONAL CONSTRAINTS #
  ##########################
  
  # Set correlations between between-factors (random intercepts) and within-
  # factors at wave 1 at 0
  RIX + RIY ~~ 0*WFX1 + 0*WFY1
'
RICLPM5.ext3.fit <- cfa(RICLPM5.ext3,
  data = datMI, 
  missing = 'ML'
)
summary(RICLPM5.ext3.fit, standardized = T)

Do we need to set the residual variances of all factors in the RI-CLPM model to 0? From my understanding, setting it to 0 implies we want perfect measurements. Is there any impact on the model if we do not do so?
Update: Sorry there is a tab within the webpage labelled Step 4 that needs to be clicked. I've updated the post with more code from the model. The model is rather long and the section is bolded in the question.

I think this Q is fine to leave open. It is phrased as a lavaan question, but it is a general question about fitting structural equation models, not lavaan programming.

I've looked at the link you provide and I don't see the residual variance restrictions. Perhaps post your whole model?

This could be a constraint that is set to aid in estimation and/or identification. You could try relaxing this constraint to see if the model converges (my guess is that it will not converge) and if so, compare the models using chi-square testing.
